# Making the hidden table non-visible in small medium (Mobile version) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a JSP page using jQuery Datatable & Bootstrap.

The desired result is grouping the existing data using various columns like the following:

```
List by:    X     Y     Z
```

Where `X`, `Y` and `Z` are the buttons which will trigger grouping by their respective columns on click.

Only for the List by `Z` type a new table is generated with the same data except for one field to avoid redirects from another page.

Using jQuery I have hidden the second table using jQuery `.hide()` in  `$(document).ready( function ()` so that only on `onclick()` of that particular `Z` type button it will be shown and existing table will be hidden.

Everything above works fine as expected for an only issue: is UI page.

When I view it in the mobile medium, I am still able to see the table which is hidden `onload()`. However, in normal desktop mode its not visible at all (as required).

Any help with my issues would be appreciated.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle for your HTML and JS/jQuery -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why don't you create the table as hidden? Why bother with hiding it in the `onload` event?

Comment: Onload of page i dont want the other table to be visible so im hiding it using $("#SecondTable").hide(); Only after onclick of the button it will call particular function among x/y/z and will do    $("#SecondTable:hidden").show(); $("#FirstTable:visible").hide();

Comment: As requested I've made the sample http://jsfiddle.net/Q5WnH/ to illustrate my issue.Unfortunately i dont have access to post the image here which will clearly tell my problem,because of missing bootstrap UI changes its not that clear in jsfiddle